# How do I blend the edges of triangles on a mesh

Tags: unity, mesh

So in Unity, I have a mesh. The mesh is made up of a series of triangles that have different textures for each triangle. The problem is that it provides a very hard edge to the triangles and I would like to have it blend between the two triangles. I feel like it probably has something to do with shaders but I don't have much knowledge about shaders. I would also like it to be dynamic. Mainly because there will be certain areas I want to blend and certain areas I want a hard edge on.

[image: Image of two triangles with different textures.]

I just want the ability to choose to have textures gradient from one texture to another slowly or be a hard line but I can only get it to be a hard line. The textures will eventually be 4k textures rather than single colors as well so it would be preferred if they overlayed based on height over each other to create a sort of overlay rather than just changing the opacity to gradient between each texture. Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to do this without a major change to your approach. By design, each triangle going down the GPU pipeline has no information about its neighbours, so as you're drawing pixels near the edge, the code has no way of knowing what texture it should start feathering toward. What you can do instead is encode the texture index to use and blending behaviour into a texture (rather than being part of the mesh), and sample a neighbourhood of that texture to determine adjacencies. The details can vary depending on your target output/look, how many textures you need, etc. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In reply to your question @DMGregory, I don't currently know how many textures I would need but in the best-case scenario, it would probably be dynamic as I add more. The final goal is a runtime modifiable terrain that has physics applied to it and has the look of a natural terrain but also the ability to have rigid objects so I could simulate the look of houses and then run things such as natural disasters over the terrain. I have been using an octree to store the data and custom classes to contain information. Perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way though? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like you're building this mesh in some kind of marching cubes or dual contouring fashion — so it can have arbitrary dynamic topology and probably uses triplanar texturing? This list of requirements makes this problem very difficult to solve, and you might need to accept loosening sone criteria to get a first prototype up and running. From there you can evaluate which additional features would get the most bang for your buck, and which are less important to the direction your game design evolves.